# tinymce not loading (Network Error)

Tags: coldfusion, tinymce-4

The text editor is not loading, I don't know why. I have a coldfusion page and I have included it as follows (Please not I am working inside sessions)under 
the  section.

```
<cfoutput>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="#rootUrl#/#myPath#/tests/user/tinymce_4.0.8/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script> 


</cfoutput>
```

Below this, I have defined styles for including CSS:

```
<cfoutput>


<style>     

                @import url('#rootUrl#/#myPath#/css/first.css');
                @import url('#rootUrl#/#myPath#/css/second.css');
                @import url('#rootUrl#/#myPath#/css/third.css');

            </style>    


</cfoutput>
```

And below this code, i have defined the code to initiate which can be found here (Under View Source):

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    convert_urls: false,
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
   });
  </script>
```

I am getting following error, could you tell me why is it like that?

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://abc.xyz.com/Public/tests/user/tinymce_4.0.8/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js


ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined


tinymce.init({
```

Please let me know what's wrong.

P.S: I have tested the editor and it works fine if I simply create a simple HTML page or even cfm page and do the above mentioned stuff(Excluding rootURL defining  steps)

Answer (score 1):

try put "http://abc.xyz.com/Public/tests/user/tinymce_4.0.8/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"(change abc.xyz.com with the actual domain) in your address bar and see if the scripts is printed in your browser

Comment: Yes, the script did load into my browser.

Comment: Ok, try to remove the tag <cfoutput>, use the script tag  without of any surrounding tag except the head

Comment: One error I am getting after removing `cfoutput` is Stntax Error ` 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//E` and another one is same as above, Reference error.